# CMake: multiple targets use the same source file

Tags: c, cmake

```
add_library(target1 funtion.c target1.c )
add_library(target2 funtion.c target2.c )
add_executable(main.out main.c) 
target_link_libraries(main.out target1 target2 ${LDFLAGS})
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` above.

Both targets need to use the source file `function.c`. It is able to run though. My concern is that maybe it is not a good behavior for writing `CMakeList.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's totally fine to use the same source file whatever number of times. Sometimes it's even necessary, if you want to compile the same source with different pre-processor/compiler flags.

But if you are concerned with compilation time, you could:

- move `funtion.c` to separate static library and link `target1` and `target2` libraries against it.
- Use [object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) for `function.c` and archive output object file to `target1` and `target2`.

Comment: Would it cause duplicated symbol if main.out link targe1 and target2, which both use function.c ?

Comment: Yes, this will lead to symbol duplication. Then you'd better to use the first option (to move `function.c` to separate library and link `target1` and `target2` against it). CMake will take care that `function` is linked only once to your `main.out`

Comment: I did on my project option 1. That caused non-weak symbols not being properly linked vs weak symbols. So I did option 2. Now I have a problem with multiple definitions of the same function. I think there's no good solution to that...

Answer (score -1):

Either you have not given enough information in your question or adding `function.c` to `target1` and `target2` will not work when you will link them together with `main.out` because you will have duplicated symbols.

If you are sure they will be no duplicated symbols (for instance because `function.c` is built with different compilation flags) then your example is correct.